# How to create annotation to register instances of a class?

Tags: java, annotations

I've never made annotations in java and I'd like to create one to register all instances of annoted classes, like this :

```
@MyAnnotation
class A{}
    
class B{
    private List<Object> registeredInstances = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void registeringMethod(Object instance){
        registeredInstances.add(instance);
    }
}
```

such as each time a new A object is created registeringMethod is called with the instance.
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this answer could help you: [Java custom annotation - calling methods with annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157760/java-custom-annotation-calling-methods-with-annotation)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with plain annotations.

You would have to use some sort of aspect oriented programming to do that. See this similar question:

[How can I use AOP to intercept the constructor of File, FileReader, FileWriter, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398260/how-can-i-use-aop-to-intercept-the-constructor-of-file-filereader-filewriter)

But it is complicated and it might be easier to just add your own registration logic to the constructor, although this a little bit frowned upon as you are registering incomplete objects.